# Can I set Lightroom's white balance picker tool to choose a supposedly white/black spot instead of neutral grey?

Tags: adobe-lightroom

I'm correcting white balance issues in **Adobe Lightroom 3**. The `white balance picker tool` in the Develop module lets me to pick a light neutral grey spot in the picture from which Lightroom automatically calculates the needed data for white balance corrections.

Can I set the picker so I could choose a spot that **should be white** (or black) **after white balance corrections?**

Compare to e.g. **Photoshop's** `curves` and `exposure` tools which both have this feature (choosing either supposedly neutral grey, white or a black spot).

I do have access to Photoshop and could correct WB with it, but I'd like to edit the files non-destructively.

Comment: perhaps try your question at http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: Why? Apple.se is for Apple's software & hardware and Lightroom is created by Adobe + it works in both Windows and OS X.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Nick](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7497/can-i-set-lightrooms-white-balance-picker-tool-to-choose-a-supposedly-white-blac/7498#7498)'s et al. answers in the similar [photo.se question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/7497/1913), mixed with own reasoning, the answer is:

**You don't have to.**

The `white balance picker tool` calibrates solely the white balance in the image, not e.g. the exposure. And if you look closely, the picker tool doesn't ask for *target neutral grey* but for just *target neutral*. One should pick a spot in the image where the channels should be approx. equal (R ≈ G ≈ B) after the automatic corrections — so it could be white, grey, black or anything in between.